# creating a long list of new variables based on existing column

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I need to create a variable for week0-week187 and doing that RBAR is just that.  data looks like:

ID  WEEK

1  0

1  28

1  186

2  187

2  30

I am trying to make  week0-week187 variables that will be 1 or 0 if the observation is in a given week, should look something like this

ID  WEEK  WEEK0  WEEK1 ...WEEK28 ... WEEK30...WEEK186  WEEK187

1  0  1 0 ...0...0...0 0

1  28 0 0 ... 1 ... 0 ... 0 0

1  186 0 0 ... 0 ... 0 ... 1 0

2  187 0 0 ... 0 ... 0 ... 0 1

2  30 0 0 ... 0 ... 1 ... 0 0

maybe a DO statement is necessary? most of the time proc sql is causing SAS to crash because my computer is a junkpiece. SAS code is preferred

Comment: cooooooode foooooooormatting... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the note "don't do this", here is how:

```
data have;
week=5;
run;

data want;
set have;
array weeks week0-week187;
do _t = 1 to dim(weeks);
 weeks[_t]=0;
end;
weeks[week+1]=1;
run;
```

Far preferable if you need this 'wide' would be to transpose things so you had 1 row per ID variable, I'd guess, which is pretty easy to do as well.  But odds are whatever you need this wide format for can be done as easily/more easily without widening.

Comment: eventually I am going to aggregate by ID. This way I can sum columns to get a frequency per week.

Comment: Right, which you can easily do without doing this... a dataset by id/week will be far more efficient.